# Getting "while expected" error in "do...while" loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I keep getting this error and I am not stuck trying to fix it.

```
package bonuscalc;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BonusCalc {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
         DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        
         int Salary;
         double NewSal, Comm;
         double p1 = 0.1;
         double p2 = 0.15;
         double p3 = 0.2;
         double p4 = 0.3;
        
         System.out.println("Welcome to Bonus Calculator");
         
         do{
            System.out.print("Enter your Salary: ");
            Salary = input.nextInt();
           }While (Salary < 0)
    
         if((Salary >  0) && (Salary <= 8000)){
             Comm = (Salary  * p1);
             NewSal = Salary + Comm;
             System.out.print("Your Commition is RM" + formatter.format(Comm)); 
             System.out.println(" and your New Salary is RM" + formatter.format(NewSal));
        
        }
          else if((Salary >  8000) && (Salary <= 15000)){
             Comm = (Salary  * p2);
             NewSal = Salary + Comm;
             System.out.print("Your Commition is RM" + formatter.format(Comm)); 
             System.out.println(" and your New Salary is RM" + formatter.format(NewSal));
            
        }
         else if((Salary >  15000) && (Salary <= 25000)){
             Comm = (Salary  * p3);
             NewSal = Salary + Comm;
             System.out.print("Your Commition is RM" + formatter.format(Comm)); 
             System.out.println(" and your New Salary is RM" + formatter.format(NewSal));
    
        }
         else if(Salary >  25000){
             Comm = (Salary  * p4);
             NewSal = Salary + Comm;
             System.out.print("Your Commition is RM" + formatter.format(Comm)); 
             System.out.println(" and your New Salary is RM" + formatter.format(NewSal));
             
        }
         else{
             System.out.println("Input invalid. Renter Salary");
            
         }
         
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have written `While` instead of `while`.

```
do {
...
} While (Salary < 0);
```

correct would be:

```
do {
...
} while (Salary < 0);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `do-while` loop has an invalid syntax. Firstly, `while` is lowercase, thus `While` is incorrect. Moreover, you are missing a semicolon.

```
do {
  System.out.print("Enter your Salary: ");
  Salary = input.nextInt();
} while (Salary < 0);
```

On a side note, in Java variables usually start with lowercase letters. It is not a strict rule, but a convention that it is prudent to conform to.